# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use bat file/CLI to run SQL script against certain Oracle database with following syntax:

```
sqlplus -L user_name/database_name@Password @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql
```

If I run this following error is returned:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle. Exitig SQL*Plus
```

At the same time **tnsping database_name** works fine & corresponding connection configuration strings are present in tnsnames.ora

Moreover if I type commands manually in a following way:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect user_name@databasename
Passowrd
```

I can connect to the database too. Any idea why I'm getting error when trying to use command I mentioned in beginning & how to fix it?

P.S. I'm doing this from Windows Server 2003 SP2 box with Oracle client v10 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this on dba.stackexchange.com - and received answer promplty:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52397/ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified

Basically the problem was wrong syntax in bat file:
Wrong command line:

sqlplus -L **user_name/tns_alias@Password** @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql

Correct one:

sqlplus -L **user_name/Password@tns_alias** @d:\my_bat_file\sql_script.sql